# material ui disable mu-focused css class on DataGrid

Tags: css, material-ui

I have a datatable as seem in pic below, when click selectbox of rowsPerPage, paper style of the table updated and new "Mui-focused" class added to div element as you seem in pic below

[image]

I dont want this "Mui-focused" class added to DOW at all, so how can I prevent it from added or how can I remove it?

here is the html:

```
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary Mui-focused css-o4rafi-MuiInputBase-root-MuiTablePagination-select">
...
</div>
```

this is my paper style defination, how should I edit this to remove that class

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiMenuItem-root': {
      fontFamily: 'inter',
    },
    padding: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 16,
    border: '1px solid #EFF0F6',
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.85)',
    fontFamily: 'Inter',
    WebkitFontSmoothing: 'auto',
    letterSpacing: 'normal',
    marginBottom: 20,
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader--filtered': {
      '& > div > div > button': {
        visibility: 'visible !important',
      },
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader--alignRight': {
      flexDirection: 'row !important',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader': {
      flexDirection: 'row !important',
      '& .MuiBadge-root > span': {
        right: '4px !important',
      },
      '& > div > div > button': {
        visibility: 'hidden',
        display: 'contents',
      },
      '&:hover': {
        '& >  div > div > button': {
          visibility: 'visible !important',
          display: 'contents',
        },
      },
    },
    '& .MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary.Mui-checked': {
      color: `${color.blue} !important`,
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainerContent': {
      width: '100%',
      '& > .MuiCheckbox-root': {
        left: 4,
      },
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-root': {
      border: 'none',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-footer': {
      border: 'none',
      display: 'block',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-footerContainer': {
      border: 'none',
      display: 'block',
    },
    '& .MuiTablePagination-selectLabel': {
      marginLeft: 220,
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
      backgroundColor: '#F8FAFD',
      borderRadius: 0,
      borderColor: '#EFF0F6',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-colCell, .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
      borderRight: 'none',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-colCellWrapper, .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer, .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
      borderBottom: '1px solid #f0f0f0',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.85)',
      fontSize: 12,
      '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within': {
        outline: 'none',
      },
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
      outline: 'none',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle': {
      fontSize: 12,
      color: 'rgba(79, 94, 116, 1)',
      userSelect: 'none',
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      fontWeight: '600',
      fontFamily: 'Inter',
    },
    '& .MuiButton-outlinedPrimary:hover': {
      border: '1px solid rgba(239, 240, 246, 1)',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderDraggableContainer': {
      flexDirection: 'row !important',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-input': {
      border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
      position: 'absolute',
      paddingTop: 12,
      paddingBottom: 12,
      paddingLeft: 31,
      paddingRight: 50,
      borderRadius: 10,
      marginLeft: 0,
      outline: '0px solid rgba(223,226,249,.1)',
      boxSizing: 'content-box',
    },
    '&  .MuiInput-input:hover': {
      border: '2px solid rgba(223,226,249,1)',
      outline: '0px solid rgba(223,226,249,.5)',
      position: 'absolute',
      marginLeft: -1,
      borderRadius: 10,
    },
    '&  .MuiInput-input:focus': {
      '-webkit-animation': 'fade 2s',
      '-moz-animation': 'fade 2s',
      border: '1px solid rgba(27,89,248,1)',
      outline: '2px solid rgba(223,226,249,1)',
      borderRadius: 10,
      position: 'absolute',
      paddingLeft: 32,
      marginLeft: -1,
      boxShadow: `${alpha('#1B59F8', 0.25)} 0 0 0 2px`,
      borderColor: '#1B59F8',
    },
  },
  },
}))
```

and here is datatable definition:

```
<DataGrid
        apiRef={apiRef}
        // Override table components
        components={{
          NoResultsOverlay: () => {
            const hasFilter = apiRef.current.state.filter.filterModel.items.length > 0
            return (
              <Text
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  height: '100%',
                }}
                variant="body1"
                text={
                  hasFilter
                    ? 'No rows found that meet your filters. Please update your filters.'
                    : 'No rows found.'
                }
              />
            )
          },
          Pagination: () => (
            <TablePagination
              className="DataTable"
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 100]}
              component="div"
              SelectProps={{
                IconComponent: KeyboardArrowDownRounded,
              }}
              count={gridVisibleRowCountSelector(apiRef.current.state)}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              page={page}
              onPageChange={handleChangePage}
              onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            />
          ),
```

any recommendation?

Comment: can you make a reproducable example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new